# update calendar from email link

Tags: email, icalendar

Obviously I'm not using the right keyword/phrases to find the information that I need. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've generated an ICS file. I put a link to this file in an email. What I would like to happen is that the recipient clicks the link and it updates their calendar (regardless of OS, platform). Currently the link simply downloads the ICS file but does not update any calendar.

Background: I belong to a non-profit organisation that runs several courses that members can subscribe to. This means that each members course list will be different therefore I can not simply send out a single list or have people subscribe to lots of different 'events' to have their calendars updated.

Is this doable or am I simply dreaming :-)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, what happens when some one clicks on an ics link depends on their device and the program that they are reading the email in, and how they have setup their defaults - eg what calednar app.  EG: I have mine setuo to download ics files for testing purposes, and if i click on a downloaded one it opens in notepad++.

Of course most people will not have that.  However, not that easy to make it happen automatically, have to tell users.

To have updates (ie syncing) happen, recipients need to **subscribe** to the link, not  import the data.   If they are not familiar with using multiple calendars, they can get confused.

instructions on google: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100 on apple calendars https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/calendar/subscribe-to-calendars-icl1022/mac.   Rather annoyingly, iphones will offer a user who clicks on a normal http..ics url an option to import all events.  To make the iphone offer the subscribe option one has to use the unofficial apple icalendar prefix webcal. So one ends up either showing both link options on a webpage, or doing device detection and showing webcal for macs.

hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the info and links.